# 3d kml barcharts in google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml, google-earth

I have some kml which looks like this:

[image]

When I view the same kml in google map, everything is 2D. Is it impossible to view 3D KML shapes (e.g barcharts) in google map?

The html of my page contains this:

```
<DIV  id="gmTest" style="width:1000px;height:1000px;border: 1px solid #979797" GoogleMapControl="" MapScale="" GoogleMapTypes="" GoogleMapStreetView="" GoogleMapPanControl="" GoogleMapZoomControl="" GoogleMapTypeControl="" GoogleMapShowTraffic=""></DIV>
```

I tried to run:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(36.964645, -122.01523),
        zoom: 18,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmTest'), mapOptions);
    map.setTilt(45);
 });
```

Is this a step in the right direction? The tilt does not change. Btw, can I massage/obtain the map without setting the options like I did? Thanks.

Comment: According to the samples, it seems like it's do-able: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#polygons
It looks like since Google Maps gives a direct look from above, you might be seeing it as 2D.

Comment: @Andy Thanks for your reply. Can you change the view angle?

Comment: Maps have a `setTilt()` method with which you should be able to change the view angle.

Comment: @Andy - could you please look at the PS?

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems the map will only tilt for "**SATELLITE and HYBRID map types, within some locations, and at some zoom levels.**" With your sample, zoomed in, it is tilted, but zoomed out it returns to overhead view.